# Exe create for UI automation using Teststack.white does not run when scheduled using Windows Task scheduler

Tags: ui-automation

I've written an exe by using TestStack.White Frameowrk  to Automate the inputs my Win Form application and it runs fine when directly launched but fails to perform the automation when called from Windows Task scheduler.

Task scheduler History for the Task reports no failure.

Can someone please help in this regard.

Completely running out of ideas as to how i can have this thing worked.

-Abishek

Comment: Is your PC locked / logged off when running task?

Comment: No the PC is not locked.The thing is even when i try to Force run from task scheduler also the automation does not start

Comment: Maybe environment variables are different on these runs. Just "print everything" at script start up. This is the last method I can suggest. :)

Comment: I have had alot of problems trying to get any uiautomation to run from a scheduled task. Although I have nothing to substatiate my claim my hunch was that it had to do with the user I was running as. If you put a try catch around your patterns I bet the first one to run will throw an invalidoperationexception with the message "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." This could be resolved by finding a way to get tash scheduler to run your task as admin.

Comment: The only way to run a UI related task using Windows Task scheduler is by specifying that the Task is Run only when the User is logged in because this option in task scheduler enables UI interactive applications to run.